# Поиск файла в папке при помощи WinApi

Tags: c++

Какая функция в WinApi32 отвечает за поиск файлов? И можно ли указывать параметры поиска? Например, найти файлы, начинающиеся на определённую букву.

Comment: Почему же вы не погуглили "WinAPI Find file"...

Answer (score 1):

```
HANDLE FindFirstFile(
LPCTSTR lpFileName, // Строка содержащая путь для поиска файлов.
LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData // Информация о найденном файле
);

BOOL FindNextFile(
HANDLE hFindFile,   // Указатель на файл из предыдущего поиска
LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData // Информация об очередном найденном файле
);
```

Comment: Написал код: LPWIN32_FIND_DATA data;
 HANDLE h = FindFirstFile("*.*", data);
 if (!(data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
  cout << "Файл найден!" << endl; Почему-то ошибка "Выражение должно иметь тип класса"

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin: Вам нужно не `LPWIN32_FIND_DATA data`, а `WIN32_FIND_DATA data`, и передавать указатель на это в функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам минимальный пример из [документации на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")    

// ...

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(TEXT("C:\\W*"), &FindFileData);
                               // ^^^^^^^^ это маска для поиска
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
    return;
}

do
{
    if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);
    }
    else
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
        filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
        filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
        _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
    }
}
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Listing failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
    return;
}

FindClose(hFind);
```

Использованные функции: [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`FindClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).