# Пройтись по файловой системе

Tags: c++, windows

Нужно на определенном диске (по-умолчанию - С) программно проверить все папки на диске, и обратится к каждому файлу
Путь файла должен быть записан в массив
Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Ответ зависит от того нужен ли вам переносимый код или речь идёт об одном семействе операционных систем.

Comment: @nzeemin windows

Comment: вот здесь ответ на ваш вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470885/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-winapi

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить об используемых функциях -- обычно это `findfirst()` и `findnext()`, но под Windows с ними вроде как проблема -- используйте `FindFirstFile()` и `FindNextFile()` из WinAPI.

Плюс у вас стоит задача обойти дерево.
Это можно сделать либо рекурсивно (состояние обхода хранится на стеке), либо циклом (подсветки которые ещё нужно обойти складываем в массив или точнее очередь).